# Special case of one author, multiple years (APA style in biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, authoryear-comp

I am trying to render the apa citation style in the biblatex package by using authoryear-comp. The special case I am using is that on the first-time in-text-citation, all the author names are printed out, but on next-time citations, all authors but first are subsumed into 'et al.' The problem of the code snippet that I use to customize this is that the functionality of the authoryear-comp gets interrupted such that the references of a single author (e.g. MacDonald, 2011, 2015) are not grouped any more (e.g. MacDonald 2011, MacDonald 2015).

The problematic code snippet is this:

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}\clearfield{namehash}}}
```

Could somebody help me to fix this peculiar behaviour? Here's the whole code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in,left=1in, right=1in, footskip=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,citetracker=true, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=6, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, dashed=false, giveninits=true, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}

%%% To make the all names visible at the first reference
\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}\clearfield{namehash}}}

%%% Use '&' instead of 'and' in parencite and bibliography list
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\&\space}

%%% Use 'and' in textcite
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{\addspace{and}\space}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{eprint}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{macdonald2015,
        title = {On Having a Farm},
        volume = {42},
        journaltitle = {Journal of Science and Stuff},
        author = {MacDonald, O.},
        date = {2015}
    }
    @article{macdonald2016,
        title = {Noise reduction in livestock},
        volume = {43},
        journaltitle = {Journal of Science and Stuff},
        author = {MacDonald, O.},
        date = {2016}
    }
    
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\title{A document}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    In this text I cite \parencite{macdonald2015, macdonald2016} for the mwe. 
    And now i cite the same clever fellow \parencite{macdonald2015, macdonald2016} again.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want (real) APA style, it's probably best to just use `biblatex-apa`''s `style=apa,` (for 7th-edition APA style) or `biblatex-apa6`'s `style=apa6,` (for 6th-edition APA style - the first citation shows all-*ish* authors, subsequent only "First + et al." is a feature of the 6th edition, in the 7th edition, it's "et al." all the way). APA style is pretty complex and trying to replicate all its intricacies with `style=authoryear-comp,` might take a while.

Comment: If you don't want actual APA style, but only something "like APA", it will depend on your exact requirements whether it is a good idea to base your style upon `style=apa,`, `style=apa6,` or a style of the generic `authoryear` family. (Generally speaking the APA styles are harder to modify because they were built specifically to implement the complex APA requirements, whereas the generic styles are supposed to be modified by end users.)

Comment: Thank for the quick answer! To use this, it seems, I would need to load apa6 package, like this `\documentclass[jou]{apa6}`, which turns my original document upside down. Are there any other possibilities to implement this `style = apa6`. At the current form of this document, it doesn't work.

Comment: No worries. Actually just `\usepackage[style=apa,citetracker=true, mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=6, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, dashed=false, giveninits=true, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}` worked for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is absolutely no need to switch document classes. The `apa6` document class is not actually affiliated with any of the `biblatex` styles. Unless you have actually checked that you need all of those options, I suggest you drop them. `style=apa,` already sets up all the option correctly for APA style. Adding more options is more likely than not to interfere with APA compliance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want (real) APA style, it's probably best to just use `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa,` (for 7th-edition APA style) or `biblatex-apa6`'s `style=apa6,` (for 6th-edition APA style - the first citation shows all-ish authors, subsequent only "First + et al." is a feature of the 6th edition, in the 7th edition, it's "et al." all the way). APA style is pretty complex and trying to replicate all its intricacies with `style=authoryear-comp,` might take a while.

Use style options only if really required. Things are already set up for proper APA compliance and additional options will probably only mess things up. The same holds for most of the additional `biblatex` code in the preamble of the example document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in,left=1in, right=1in, footskip=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{macdonald2015,
  title = {On Having a Farm},
  volume = {42},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Science and Stuff},
  author = {MacDonald, O.},
  date = {2015}
}
@article{macdonald2016,
  title = {Noise reduction in livestock},
  volume = {43},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Science and Stuff},
  author = {MacDonald, O.},
  date = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  In this text I cite \parencite{macdonald2015, macdonald2016} for the mwe. 
  And now i cite the same clever fellow \parencite{macdonald2015, macdonald2016} again.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you don't want actual APA style, but only something "like APA", it will depend on your exact requirements whether it is a good idea to base your style upon `style=apa,`, `style=apa6,` or a style of the generic `authoryear` family. (Generally speaking the APA styles are harder to modify because they were built specifically to implement the complex APA requirements, whereas the generic styles are supposed to be modified by end users.)